# Store and retrieve BYTE* data from MYSQL in C++

Tags: c++

I am developing a fingerprint database as my college project. I am using Secugen U10 fingerprint sensor with Pi Zero using C++ language. I have tried many ways to do so and researched on stack overflow for the same. I found the following code for storing the BYTE* to MySQL database.

```
int escaped_size = 2 * sizeof(minutiaeBuffer1) + 1;
char chunk[escaped_size];
mysql_real_escape_string(conn, chunk, (const char*)minutiaeBuffer1, sizeof(minutiaeBuffer1));
const char* query_template = "INSERT INTO `students_details`(`user_id`, `batch`, `roll_no`, `university_id`, `admission_id`, `fingerprint`, `enrolled`) VALUES ('100','1','46','TVE17MCA042','171152','%s', '100')";
size_t template_len = strlen(query_template);
int query_buffer_len = template_len + escaped_size;
char query[query_buffer_len];
int query_len = snprintf(query, query_buffer_len, query_template, chunk);
mysql_real_query(conn, query, query_len);
```

Here, The minutiaeBuffer1 is the BYTE* data. I tried to retrive the data as follows:-

```
mysql_query(conn, finalQuery);
result = mysql_store_result(conn);
int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
row = mysql_fetch_row(result);
std::string str = row[0];
BYTE* fingerPrintFromDatabase = new BYTE [str.size() + 1];
```

The fingerPrintFromDatabase variable display different values at every execution. I knew this my printing it as string. Please help.

Comment: "with Pi Zero using C" - If you are using C, why did you tag the question C++? They are *entirely different* languages.

Comment: Where is the part where you put the data into `fingerPrintFromDatabase `?

Comment: Also this is not C - I can tell because it uses `new` - @JesperJuhl

Comment: @user253751 Ohh, I couldn't tell from that jumbled mess. But sure, if there's a `new` in there it obviously has to be parsed as C++..

Comment: @JesperJuhl By the way, if this was a question entirely about the MySQL API then I would leave both the C and C++ tags on, since the question would be answerable by people familiar with either (I'm sure C programmers can understand `new BYTE[...]` easily enough). But since `std::string` is also involved I will only tag it as C++.